# Dealiasing Types in Scala reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

How can I resolve aliases given a `Type`? I.e.

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

type Alias[A] = Option[Option[A]]
val tpe = typeOf[Alias[_]] 
val ExistentialType(quantified, underlying) = tpe
```

How do I get `Option[Option[_$1]]` from `underlying` (or from `tpe`)? I know that `typeSymbol` does resolve aliases, but it seems to lose the parameters in the process:

```
scala> val tT = typeOf[Alias[_]].typeSymbol
tT: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = class Option

scala> tT.asType.toType
res3: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Option[A]

scala> tT.asType.typeParams
res4: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = List(type A)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method turns out to be called [`normalize`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.5/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Types$TypeApi) in 2.10 (deprecated and `dealias` added in 2.11). Don't know how I managed to miss it during my first search.